# How to make DataLoader load correct batch_size data while using pytorch_geometric Data object?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to [pytorch_geometric](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric).

Here is my code to create a DataLoader which contains 5 samples, and each sample was represented by a 1 * 10 matrix.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch_geometric.data import Data, DataLoader

x = torch.tensor(np.random((5, 10))
y = torch.tensor(np.random((5, 1))
data = Data(x = x, y = y)
loader = DataLoader([data], batch_size=2)
```

When I set batch_size to 2, I'd like the loader to load my 5 samples by 2 2 1, but now it pushes out all data in one batch, below code is the print result.

```py
for batch in loader:
    print(batch)

# Batch(batch=[5], x=[5, 10], y=[5, 1])
```

Please let me know how can I achieve the result I want if you are familiar with that.

By the way, I learned this from pytorch_geometric official repository dataset like [this](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/a5a6a5077bfbfcc04ef52130c01ef56e627b516b/torch_geometric/datasets/actor.py#L84).